# Cannot get bxSlider plugin to render

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

Here is the website to get the plugin: http://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions

I have followed all directions to the best of my knowledge.

First, all scripts included do render fine on view page source. So something has to be wrong with the jquery call. However, on firefox firebug in the console there are absolutely no errors.

Here is the jquery library, css, and javascript call.
Also, everything is in the head of the page and I am using correct library version.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="components/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="components/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   //boxslider for portfolio
    $('#bxslider').bxSlider({
     mode: 'fade',
     captions: true

   });
   });

</script>
```

Markup html:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Some of Our Projects</h2>
    <ul id="bxslider">
      <li><img src="../../images/shots/ecommerce.png" title="Happy trees" /></li>
      <li><img src="../../images/shots/templateviewthread.jpg" title="Funky roots" /></li>
      <li><img src="../../images/shots/templateprofile.jpg" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
      <li><img src="../../images/shots/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
      <li><img src="../../images/shots/valleyvuecoatings.jpeg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
      <li><img src="../../images/shots/thegazebo.jpeg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--/.container-->
```

Comment: Can you remake the issue on fiddle? And is this locally? I have used bxSlider on a lot of sites and had no issues :)

Comment: Bojan Petkovski Sure, I can make a fiddle. This is locally and on the Laravel framework. That should not matter though.

Comment: Bojan Petkovski http://jsfiddle.net/ujtdq0wr/

Comment: @Bobby, you must have an issue with your script / style. I've updated your jsfiddle with the plugin and it works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/milz/ujtdq0wr/1/

Comment: @BojanPetkovski Thank you, but how did you get the updated version to work. What did you change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your fiddle is not working. Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/ujtdq0wr/2/

First of all, if you are working locally you need to add http to the link from google apis

So from this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

TO this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can check if the bxslider script and css file are loaded on your page :)

**UPDATE**

Call bxSlider in the template file where you have the // navigation click actions on line 260. SO before them just copy the code below :)

```
$('#bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: true
});
```

Comment: Whoops, I had a typo but that did not fix it.

Comment: Here is my template to get a better view to maybe see what is going on. http://laravel.io/bin/LN8Kx

Comment: I am noticing that you are missing the opening body tag. Secondly how are you inserting the content for the page /  slider?

Comment: strangely also there is a ") hanging in the markup that is no where to be found in the markup. I am not sure if that is the cause. Something from the jquery. Here is an image http://postimg.org/image/oc8u2ejrp/

Comment: The opening body tag is carried over to the page that holds the content. It is the Laravel blade templating system. That should not matter with the body as my other jquery is working. As long as the body lines up in the markup.

Comment: You should call the slider in the template file. Check the updated answer :)

Comment: I mean this http://laravel.io/bin/wa8VK ANd there is an update, at the bottom of my answer there is UPDATE with bold font :)

Comment: sorry update did not refresh until a minute later. I am getting errors now in the console log http://postimg.org/image/pa9hj639d/

Comment: That is because you are calling jQuery again on line 256. Comment that line and call jquery just in the head and only once :)

Comment: ok, made some progress. Now the image slider images(arrows) are showing up in the header content and all the way down the page the caption is showing up. This is strange. And the error TypeError: $(...).rotate is not a function still exists.

Comment: You need to call the rotate plugin in the same place where you call bxslider, so move $("#world").rotate({... to the same place. And this question went beyond the scope of it's answer. If you found my answers helpfull please accept the answer and open a new question for the remaining issues on your page :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run this plugin at jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/vs9j9dzu/
Take a llok to what scripts are loading and jQuery version and try the same with your site.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      //boxslider for portfolio
      $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        captions: true

      });
    });

    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li>
        <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" title="Funky roots" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="The long and winding road" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" />
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: thank you but no change. I have the correct library version included along with the correct css and js files.